# How do I set up a new database with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In my start menu, I have Microsoft SQL Server Express 2008 R2 > Configuration Tools.  In this folder, I have SQL Server Configuration Manager, SQL Server Error and Usage Reporting, and SQL Server Installation Center.  Where do I go to create a new database from scratch?  I must be looking in the wrong place.

**Edit:**  What I am trying to do here is import two Excel sheets containing data from two other non-SQL-Server databases so I can run a few queries for data comparison.  I don't have Acceess, otherwise I'd use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out that I didn't have SQL Server Management Studio installed.  I had to open up SQL Server Installation Center.  From the left pane, I selected Installation.  In the right pane, I then selected New SQL Server stand-alone installation.  I will be marking this as the answer.